# Best practice to present storage to KVM guest VM for storage server for iScsi target

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, fedora, storage-area-network

Hi I'm building out a storage sever that will consist of a KVM Fedora-Server host with a Fedora Server guest VM.  I have a 20tb SSD Raid 6 array that I want to act as my storage target ultimately this will serve as a storage target for VMWare hosts.  This is my first time building out this type of server on Fedora and KVM and am modeling it after SAM-SD solution.  My question is what is the best practice to present my storage volume to to the guest server ?  There seems to be a multitude of different solutions to doing this but my primary concerns are performance and, reliability, and ease of backup.

(Haven't decided on the iScsi or NFS for this implementation and will probably test both before putting into production.  Network will be 25gb infiniband).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the overhead to a minimum. Don't use KVM for a storage server, just set up NFS or iSCSI and serve your hypervisor hosts via a dedicated network.

Comment: Is there no benefit to being able backup the guest VM ?

Comment: Backup and restore work fine on bare metal. Snapshots can be accomplished via the filesystem.